# Sorry, that page does not exist code 34

Tags: php, api, twitter

```
    $consumerkey = 'HGJHGJHBJHGUYjhvbjhvGUYG';
    $consumersecret = 'HGFHGFhghgHGFHGhgvchGHGVhgvcHG';
    $accesstoken = 'gvHGHGVHGVhgVHGVhgvhgvhv';
    $accesstokensecret = 'hgHGJHGVHJGVjhgvGVhgvHGVhjgvHGVhgVj';

    $twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

    $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Sunshine&count=10');

print_r($tweets);
```

Gives me this error:

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => Sorry, that page does not exist [code] => 34 ) ) )
```

How do I resolve this? Since everything I throw at to this script gives me an error.

Comment: You should first try explaining what you are trying to achieve clearly.. then you can reference your source code. StackOverflow is harsh... people will down vote your question for lack of details information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you're using, TwitterOAuth, doesn't take a full URL in its `get()` method. Instead you need to pass in the path as well as an array of parameters.

Per the documentation, this:

```
$twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Sunshine&count=10');
```

Should be:

```
$twitter->get('statuses/user_timeline', ['screen_name' => 'Sunshine', 'count' => 10]);
```

Documentation: https://twitteroauth.com/

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to access the information of users who may have deleted their account/tweet/comment. Thus, this error. If you are parsing through multiple users, I will suggest you make use of a try exception block:

```
try:
    user_tweets = api.user_timeline(user_name, count=10)
except Exception as e:
    print(e, 'User ->', user_name)
```

A quick way to verify whether the users in the exception really have deleted their account/status will be go and check on twitter. For example, if you want to check whether `xyz` user has deleted his/her account to go and check whether the given `https://twitter.com/xyz` exists.